# Steam API Failing to get inventory

Tags: steam

I usually try not to post on here because after doing a lot of research or just messing with stuff I can usually figure the problem out but with this I've run out of ideas. I keep getting rate limited hard by the steam API but only on one computer on my network and its the one that I use to run code and bot for like discord or steam with because i never turn it off but I'm thinking it may be a setting or firewall issue or something because when I'm accessing the steam API through this URL or anything to do with inventory its getting rate limited [https://steamcommunity.com/inventory/${steamid}/252490/2/](https://steamcommunity.com/inventory/$%7Bsteamid%7D/252490/2/) but its also not just the API because even opening my inventory on that computer normally I just get a blank page. The response code I'm getting is `429` which is for too many requests but it will only let me make maybe one request a hour. Sometimes not even one. I've tried looking at other posts and the problem they get is either accessing it wrong or just making too many requests. And its only inventories that has a issue. Pulling prices from the Steam market has no problem. Steam works completely fine on my main computer and even the endpoint works fine and it takes a lot of refreshing to get it to rate limit. Got any idea of what it could be?

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel No it does not. Using ?count=2000 in the URL it still gets rate limited after only 1 request. And i would still have the issue of not being able to access inventories normally using https://steamcommunity.com/profiles/steamid/inventory/